# Android Studio cannot read from file, does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-io

I'm trying to read from a file in Android Studio, in a small Java app.  So I'm trying this:

```
    File test = new File("C:\\testing\\testFile.dat");
    if (test.exists()) {
        System.out.println("test exists");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("test doesn't exist");
    }
```

The file definitely exists, but it keeps on reporting that the file doesn't exist.  I was able to work around this with another file by using the `AssetManager` and reading it through a stream, but the method I'm calling now requires a `File`'s absolute path, but it's point blank refusing to find the file.

Am I doing something dumb, or misunderstanding something?

**UPDATE**
Ok, thanks for the input, I've now solved the problem.  First I had to upload the file I wanted into the virtual device's storage, then I was able to get the path to it.

```
File test = new File(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "testFile.dat");
```

Comment: That is a file on your development machine, not on the Android device/emulator. An app cannot read that directly like that.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I had a feeling that was the case.  Is there a way I can get the path of the file using the AssetManager?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. If you're asking if you can get a `File` object or a straight file path for something in your project's `assets/` folder, then no, 'cause they aren't files on the device/emulator. They're packed into your apk. You can get an `InputStream` or an `AssetFileDescriptor`, but if you absolutely have to have a file path, you'll need to first copy it out to the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the method I'm calling now requires a File's absolute path

Assets are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

Ideally, you switch to some library that supports `InputStream` or similar options, rather than requiring a filesystem path. If that is not an option, you can always get the `InputStream` from `AssetManager` and use that to make a copy of the data in some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). You can then pass the path to that file to this method.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this file in your `assets/` folder inside the android project and access using the following code.

```
val inputSteam =  assets.open("testFile.dat")
```

or place it inside the `res/raw` folder and access it like below.

```
val inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.testFile)
```

We can't access a file on a development machine like this and won't be available on an android device so it will break so it's better if we move this somewhere inside the project and access it as above.